# problema error consulta mysql entrega valores nulos

Tags: mysql, sql

hola tengo una consulta sql y cuando la ejecuto pasa que me entrega valores nulos nose por que sera podrian ver si hay algun error, todas las tablas tienen datos

tablas

- participanes
- enrolamiento
- curso_unico
- curso_generico
- comunas
- institucion

modelo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la consulta

```
SELECT Count(e.rut_participante) AS cantidad, 
       cg.nombre_curso, 
       cg.costo, 
       cu.id_curso_unico, 
       cu.duracion_h, 
       cu.jornada_h, 
       cu.cantidad_participantes, 
       cu.fecha_inicio, 
       cu.fecha_termino, 
       cu.hora_desde, 
       cu.hora_hasta, 
       c.nombre_comuna 
FROM   participanes p, 
       enrolamiento e, 
       curso_unico cu, 
       curso_generico cg, 
       comunas c, 
       institucion i 
WHERE  i.rut_institucion = cu.rut_institucion 
       AND p.rut_participante = e.rut_participante 
       AND c.id_comuna = cu.id_comuna 
       AND cg.id_curso = cu.id_curso 
       AND cu.id_curso_unico = e.id_curso_unico 
       AND e.id_curso_unico = 1
```

resultado Consulta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito los siguientes campos

- curso_generico: nombre_curso,costo
  -curso_unico:id_curso_unico,duracion_h,jornada_h,cantidad_participantes,fecha_inicio,fecha_termino

-comuna:nombre_comuna

-institucion:razon_social

-conteo de los rut(clave foranea de participantes) que hay en la tabla enrolamiento

todo esto segun cuando el id de la tabla curso_unico sea igual a 1

Comment: uf, hay muchos temas con tu código. Sería bueno entender qué es lo que quieres obtener. Por otro lado, en el modelo dices que la tabla `enrolamiento` tiene un `rut_estudiante`, pero en la condición del `join` (que a todo esto usas joins implícitos, y no explícitos como es la buena práctica) tienes `rut_participante` (además que el nombre de la tabla en el modelo es `participanes`)

Comment: @Lamak al crear la base de datos arregle  esos detalles de las clave foránea de la tabla enrolamiento, sabes por que podría dar valores nulos la consulta siendo que las tablas están relacionadas y con datos y enlazo todas las tablas con sus claves respectivas

Comment: simplemente porque no están todos los datos para el filtro que usaste. Y nuevamente te animo a que expliques qué es lo que te gustaría obtener como resultado, para ayudarte con una consulta que no tenga los problemas actuales.

Comment: @Lamak edite la pregunta y agrege los datos que necesito

Comment: te puedo ayudar con la consulta, pero sería bueno que revises tu data para que entiendas el por qué no te aparecen resultados

Comment: @Lamak si eso estoy revisando ahora

Answer (score 1):

Ok, primero que todo, te pido que por favor dejes de usar joins implícitos (porque están deprecados) y uses joins explícitos.
Por otro lado, si bien MySQL permite (en contra del estándar) realizar funciones de agrupación en sólo algunas columnas de tu  `SELECT`, sin usar un `GROUP BY`, es una pésima práctica, porque los valores para esas columnas son arbitrarios (y además porque no es estándar).

Reescribí tu consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT Count(Distinct e.rut_participante) AS cantidad, 
       cg.nombre_curso, 
       cg.costo, 
       cu.id_curso_unico, 
       cu.duracion_h, 
       cu.jornada_h, 
       cu.cantidad_participantes, 
       cu.fecha_inicio, 
       cu.fecha_termino, 
       cu.hora_desde, 
       cu.hora_hasta, 
       c.nombre_comuna 
FROM  participanes p
INNER JOIN enrolamiento e
    ON p.rut_participante = e.rut_participante 
INNER JOIN curso_unico cu
    ON cu.id_curso_unico = e.id_curso_unico 
INNER JOIN curso_generico cg
    ON cg.id_curso = cu.id_curso 
INNER JOIN comunas c
    ON c.id_comuna = cu.id_comuna 
INNER JOIN institucion i 
    ON i.rut_institucion = cu.rut_institucion 
WHERE  e.id_curso_unico = 1 
GROUP BY cg.nombre_curso, 
        cg.costo, 
        cu.id_curso_unico, 
        cu.duracion_h, 
        cu.jornada_h, 
        cu.cantidad_participantes, 
        cu.fecha_inicio, 
        cu.fecha_termino, 
        cu.hora_desde, 
        cu.hora_hasta, 
        c.nombre_comuna 
;
```

Si bien esto no va a arreglar tu situación de que no te devuelva datos, porque eso pasa porque en algún lado de los joins no se cumple alguna de las condiciones.

Comment: hice consulta con la tabla curso_generico y curso_unico y no entrego nada,intentare la consulta que entregaste

Comment: igual da vacio con la consulta nueva creo que podria ser un problema de las claves foraneas

Comment: Eso es lo que decía en mi respuesta, que te entregará el mismo resultado. Prueba cambiando cada `INNER JOIN` por un `LEFT JOIN`, ahí verás cuáles columnas tienen resultado `NULL`, para que entiendas en qué tabla te están faltando los datos

Comment: Fue un error como se dice capa 8, simplemente el id 1 no existe y como estoy acostumbrado a que los id sean enteros no me di cuenta que era un id alfanumérico,gracias por aclararme eso de la consulta de los join explicitos, y perdon si te hice perder tu tiempo